# How to import the same package multiple times

Tags: python, import, sentry

I am using sentry_sdk to log my errors and based upon a certain host value, I would like my error to go to that host's sentry. I have the following code:

```
for host in hosts:
    import sentry_sdk
    sentry_sdk.init(dsn=config.get(f'SENTRY_DSN_{host}'), environment=os.getenv('ENV')])
    sentry_hosts[host] = sentry_sdk
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have two concerns:

- sentry limitation: it can only be initialized with one configuration
- multiple imports: will importing the same package over and over overwrite the same resource?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/198

Comment: What's the use case here? Sentry already tracks the hostname of the server which logs the exception, so I don't see why you'd need a different DSN based on which host sent the exception.

Comment: host might have been the incorrect variable to use. My service has multiple clients which hit our APIs. Depending on the client, we need to route the errors to the correct DSN